# Why email to me & list doesn't show up twice?

Tags: email, mailing-lists

Let's say I've joined `amazing-list@not-boring-lists.org`. My friend sends an email To me and she also CC's `amazing-list@not-boring-lists.org`. I would naively expect the email to show up twice in my inbox, but (thankfully!) it appears only once.

*Question 1:* Which is the smart program that figures out I only really want to see just one copy of the email? Is it my local email client, my server, the list server or something else?

*Question 2:* How is this small piece of magic achieved? Is it part of a more general optimization? Are there similar pieces of magic going on under the hood that make email smoother?

If relevant, I use Thunderbird on Linux.

Comment: You email was in the "to" field, therefore the listserver knows who in the list would not want another copy, as they will have already received it. Sadly though, your friend was daft enough to expose your email address to a public group.

Comment: Who keeps marking these questions as "opinion-based"...

Comment: @Mokubai thanks for the explanation. Does this mean that the list server just assumes that my friend's mail server will work as expected and the mail will reach me? In this sense the list server is risking a bit that I won't receive the email, right? Furthermore, what really happened is that my friend was responding to me on a thread I had responded to in the past, so she didn't expose anything new.

Comment: @Mokubai "_your friend was daft enough to expose your email address to a public group_" If the list server is "clever" enough to not send a copy to someone already present on the _incoming_ email's recipient list, it's _probably_ clever enough to not disclose that name to everyone else on the list (it probably sends a copy to everyone on the list, without disclosing other members of the list).

Answer (score 0):

In this case it is almost certainly the listserver that is deciding not to send emails to people who are already direct recipients.

The reason I say this is because the listserver is the *only* point that has access to *all* the recipients at the same time.

1. If you receive an email from both sources then your email client will only see an email from `amazing-list@not-boring-lists.org` and another one from your friend, it cannot guarantee that they are not the same message as they would have different headers and different sources.
2. your friends email server will have no idea whether or not you are a part of the listserver group and must therefore dutifully attempt to send to both.
3. the listserver will recieve an email from your friend with both the list address and your address. This server knows you are part of the list and is the only server that does. It can see that you are a recipient and, assuming point 2 above, that you will have already been sent a copy.

Therefore this "magic" is handled by the listserver.

To address your comment as to why the list server "assumes" correct operation of your friends mail server, the answer is "because it recieved a copy of the message at all". It can only assume that the sender sent what was requested of it and cannot make any other assumptions about the operation of another device on the internet. Your friends server was told to send it to two people, so two messages should have been sent. It correctly recieved a message, so can only assume that the other message was sent and recieved correctly as well.

The underlying protocols that make up the internet are built on making sure that what two endpoints see, even over unstable connections, is a stable link or message. There are retries, retransmission, rerouting and management that makes an inherently erratic collection of data packets seem like they were sent in a sensible order and as intended.

That this worked at all is a fundamental feature of how the internet was built. You assume that each layer below yours has done it's job correctly. If you don't make that assumption then you're going to be sending and receiving several times more than you ever wanted to for no real benefit.

Comment: Point (1) is not quite right. My client shows both the "To: me" and the "CC: list" header, so in principle it could be the smart one and show only one of the two identical emails in case it had received one copy from the listserver and another directly from my friend. The same smartness could be employed by my server as well. (This would work only if both the listserver and my friend's server sent with both headers untouched.)

Comment: But they wouldn't pass through untouched. The one from the listserver would have at least one more server (the listserver server itself) as a bounce inbetween, thus making it a distinctly new message. The only way not to get two distinct messages is number 3.

Comment: Still, my server/client could compare only the user-facing parts of the email (To, (B)cc, Subject, body). Probably that's not what is really going on, but it could technically happen.

Comment: @Orfeas: No, most listservers also preserve the Message-ID header.

Comment: @grawity: So my client or server could alternatively compare Message-ID headers only and show/forward only one to me?